# How to ignore certain LaTeX commands and options with aspell?

Tags: bash, latex, aspell

I use the following command to make a spell check on my thesis:

```
cat thesis.tex | aspell list --mode=tex -d en_US -p ./wordlist.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

It uses my custom word list file and reduces all spelling mistakes to unique
entries.
Unfortunately, aspell does not ignore commands such as \lstinline{} which contain code.
Neither does it ignore the name of options such as "basicstyle".
It would make sense to check the values of options (such as "caption") but the rest should be ignored.
How can I ignore such commands and options?